# Как написать программу без переменной логического типа?

Tags: c++

> Написать программу нахождения максимального из двух вещественных чисел X и Y с использованием тернарной операции. Написать два варианта программы. С использованием переменной логического типа для определения условия и без неё.

Как понять вторую часть задания?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x, y;
    
    cout << "enter x ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "enter y ";
    cin >> y;
    
    x > y ? cout << x : cout << y<< endl;

    if (x > y)
        cout << x;
    else
        cout << y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И в чем проблемы? Кстати, лучше писать `cout << (x > y ? x : y) << endl;` — и короче, и понятнее...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Написать два варианта программы. С использованием переменной логического типа для определения условия и без неё."

С использованием:

```
    int main() {
        double x, y;
        cout << "enter x ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "enter y ";
        cin >> y;
        
        bool u = x>y;
        cout << (u ? x : y) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Без использования:

```
    int main() {
        double x, y;
        cout << "enter x ";
        cin >> x;
        cout << "enter y ";
        cin >> y;
        
        cout << (x>y ? x : y) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

И спасибо Harry за ценный комментарий!

(Извините, но задача - тривиальная.)